# SKStoreRevieController requestReview() method causing UI lag when failing to connect to iTunes

Tags: swift, multithreading, storekit

StoreKit's SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() method makes it simple to prompt a user for an App Store Review.

But when a proxy/firewall is blocking the app from connecting to iTunes, I am seeing significant UI lag, where touch events do not work for several seconds (even when calling the requestReview method on a background thread). It seem's these attempts to connect to iTunes to prompt the review, are clogging the main thread

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
       SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
 }
```

Is there any way around this? I would't want a user to experience this lag, even if they are connected to wifi that has iTunes blocked.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you solve it? Same issue